# Downloading file from FTP server using Qt framework

Tags: qt, ftp

I'm trying to implement one window based application in Qt 4.8.5. That will log in to the remote FTP server and downloads the latest file present in the server. Please suggest me any examples pertaining to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start from this 'official' example:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-qftp.html

To know the files to download you may store on client side the timestamp of the last file you've downloaded. Call the list() method for the directories you want to check, connect the signal listInfo() to check the [QUrlInfo::lastModified()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qurlinfo.html#lastModified) with your timestamp and if needed, start the download.